# Estimation for operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras, estimation, banach-algebras

I have seen the following estimation in some proofs:
$A^*B^*BA \leq ||B||_{op}^2 \,A^*A$ for $A,B\in B(H)$

I don't see where this inequality comes from. Do you have a proof? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\|B\|^2A^*A-A^*B^*BA=A^*(\|B\|^2I-B^*B)A\ge 0$$